# How do I convert JSON to a Data Frame

Tags: r, json, dataframe

everyone.
I have data from Instagram using this request:
https://www.instagram.com/netflix/?__a=1

1. How can I read the JSON File?
2. How do I convert JSON to a Data Frame in R or other applications?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Many R reading-functions take urls, perhaps `json <- readLines("https://...")`. Once you get there, use `jsonlite::fromJSON` to extract into a `list`. I won't go any further, since this is *nothing* like a simple 2D frame, too  many nooks and crannies to be handled generically. At a *minimum* (and it's barely scraping by), you need to define how you expect this more than 5-nested list into a 2d frame, with expected output. It would be much better if you showed effort and code attempted. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

To read the JSON it's as simple as this

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON("https://www.instagram.com/netflix/?__a=1")
```

Now turning it into a data.frame is a completely bespoke problem - JSON returns a key-value store, which can be very unique in it's 'shape'. Data.frames are typically rectangular (tabular) data, whereas key-value stores can be extremely unique in their strcuture. So TL;DR, you have to think about which parts of the list you keep, or how you manipulate it into a data.frame.